# Problem with multiple promises when trying to get downloadURL's from Cloud Storage

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, firebase-storage, angular-promise

So what im trying to do is store each downloadURL from multiple promises(files im uploading) in an array,while looping through them.
What happens is i get the first output for every item no matter how many items i get, it just keeps giving me the first downloadURL from the first promise.

If i could somehow label each of the promises so they dont go over eachother and give me the same value for each file, or myb stop each one and wait till the first one finishes to start the second. first solution sounds way better to me but i still have no idea how would i do it.

```
   pushUpload(upload: Upload) {

    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    this.uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

    this.uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot) =>  {
        // upload in progress
        upload.progress = Math.ceil((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100)
      },
      (error) => {
        // upload failed
        console.log(error)
      },
      () => {
        // upload success
        this.uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
          this.uploadInfo.push(url)
        })
      })
  };
```

```
  uploadMultiple() {
    let files = this.selectedFiles
    let filesIndex = _.range(files.length)
    _.each(filesIndex, (idx)=>{
      this.currentUpload = new Upload(files[idx]);
      this.service.pushUpload(this.currentUpload);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Ok I don't really understand the question, but why all the _ usage? You can just do `files.forEach(file => this.service.pushUpload(new Upload(file)))` right?

Comment: yeayea its just the way someone else started coding it but it dosent make a difference

Comment: Ok, so where's the problem here? If it's just the waiting until all Promises finish then you could turn your Promises into Observables and spread your array of Observables into a `forkJoin` call. That will wait until all Observables finish to execute. I'll write you up an answer with that approach

Comment: sorry about my wording of things, english isnt my first language,i updated the question might be more understable now

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem, but not your code, but I think that `forkJoin` is a very good solution to make sure that you get a neat array with the results of each Promise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RxJS to turn your Promises into Observables and use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to wait until each one of them finishes.

```js
import { from, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

let promises = thePromiseArray();
forkJoin(...promises.map(promise => from(promise))).subscribe(
  results => {
    console.log("This is an array of the results of each Promise:", results);
  }
)
```

You can also use `pipe` to add extra operators to all downloads, or each download individual. For example you could use `timeout` to make sure you don't wait longer then some amount of time:

```js
forkJoin(...promises.map(promise => from(promise).pipe(
  timeout(25000) // This is applied to each download individually
))).pipe(
  // Any operators added here would be applied to the forkJoin, so all downloads as a whole
).subscribe(
  results => {
    console.log("This is an array of the results of each Promise:", results);
  }
)
```